What does トコ mean in this sentence
TW: Some minor adult content. I'm not sure if this is warrented but I know anyone of any age could be on here so just in case.
Context: In the scene, a girl is describing why she hates someone. She says the following

あと女しか助けないトコ　性欲丸出しな感じで気持ち悪い

My question is what is トコ doing here? From what I know, the sentence translates to "Also, he doesn't save anyone but women, he seems obviously horny and it feels gross". What does this トコ add to the sentence? What is it doing both tonally and structurally? What's it's purpose in coming at the end of statement?

トコ is a casual version of ところ. In this context, it means something like a trait or a characteristic.

あと女しか助けないところ（が）性欲丸出しな感じで気持ち悪い
Also, his trait where he assists girls only gives an impression of fully exposing his sexual desires, and it is fucking disgusting.

Sorry if my translation is off but it is not my speciality.
